# Worklight: Screen Flickering after upgrade on WL 5.0.6

Tags: iphone, upgrade, ibm-mobilefirst

I am seeing flickering on some of the screens' titles area in my WL App. There is no new change in the code besides WL version upgrade from 5.0.5 to 5.0.6.

For example, i went into a page and then using Jquery changePage i moved back to previous page, then the title of previous page starts flickering.

> $.mobile.changePage("#prvPage", { transition: "slide"});

Before upgrade it was working fine. And this happens on some screens and not on all screens/pages.

what could be the reason, any idea? please share.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its related to the same, but I have this problem in v6.0 when the 'Design Mode' has been selected on a html. Deselect it and things become okay.

Regards,
Elvis.

Comment: Well, I am facing it on the deployed version on device. Yes i have seen the design mode jerks.

Comment: i applied fix pack and it removed issue.